# .live() jQuery - how to change my events

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

How do i change these events to .live() event handler?

I thought I could just change $(document).ready(function() ...to.... $(document).live(function() as well as .keydown and .data to .live but i can't seem to get it to work... help please.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#number').bind('keyup change focus', function(){
                        var field = this;
                        timer = setTimeout(function(){runSearch(field);}, 444);});                      
                $('#number').keydown(function(){clearTimeout(timer);});                 
                //url selection by specifics                
            $('#phone_book tr').data('bgcolor', '#aaf').hover(function(){
                 var $this = $(this);
                 var newBgc = $(this).data('bgcolor');
            $(this).data('bgcolor', $(this).css('background-color')).css('background-color', newBgc);
                 });  
                //url selection by specifics  
                $("#phone_book tr").click(function(){
                        var id = $(this).children().first().html();
                        var type = $(this).parents('table').siblings('div.module_header').html().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Don't change the .ready(). You only need to change the handlers for elements that don't exist after the page has been loaded initially. So for every dynamically added element you'll have to replace the handler name. BUT: You should use .on() because .live() will soon be removed.

Comment: so .bind, .keydown, .data, .click all need to be changed to .on()

Comment: .data() is not an event handler, and as such does not need to be changed. .data() stores or retrieves a specific set of data on/from the jQuery object(s) specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of your code with the .on function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#number').on('keyup change focus', function(){
             var field = this;
             timer = setTimeout(function(){runSearch(field);}, 444);});                      
            $('#number').keydown(function(){clearTimeout(timer);});                 
                //url selection by specifics

            $('#phone_book tr').data('bgcolor', '#aaf').hover(function(){
                    var newBgc = $(this).data('bgcolor');
                    $(this).data('bgcolor', $(this).css('background-color')).css('background-color', newBgc);});  
                //url selection by specifics  
            $("#phone_book tr").on('click', function(){
                     var id = $(this).children().first().html();
                     var type = $(this).parents('table').siblings('div.module_header').html().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 6):

change

```
.bind(...
```

to

```
.on(...
```

.live() is actually deprecated.

For ones like .keyup(), .keydown(), change those to .on('keydown'... etc.

Comment: Note however it takes more than simply changing .bind to .on, you also have to delegate from a parent.

Comment: not all the time. only depends on the exact situation. if your targeted element is expected to get removed and re-added, then yea, delegation would be necessary.

Comment: The question specifically asks how to change to .live which suggests delegated events.

Answer (score 1):

Change .bind() to .live()

Keep in mind that live() is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery and you should use on() instead. Some of your events may also require the older delegate() method.

```
$('#number').live('keyup change focus', function(){
    var field = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){runSearch(field);}, 444);});                      
    $('body').delegate('#number', 'keydown', function(){clearTimeout(timer);});                 
        //url selection by specifics                
        $('body').data('bgcolor', '#aaf').delegate('#phone_book tr', 'hover, function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var newBgc = $(this).data('bgcolor');
            $(this).data('bgcolor', $(this).css('background-color')).css('background-color', newBgc);
    });
```

Comment: can't get the .data() event to function after the keydown and new results are being displayed.

Comment: .data() is not an event - are you talking about the hover()?

Comment: sorry, not the data function... yes hover

Comment: Without having the markup or a sample to work with I can only guess at this point. Can you set up a jsfiddle?